# Parsing a Continuity of Care Document (CCD) with T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, ccd, c-cda

I've figured out how to do some basic parsing of a CCD using T-SQL and thought I would share the result.

If anyone knows a better way to do this, please feel free to comment. I'm particularly interested in reducing the text associated with the namespace declaration.

I know I could simply remove the namespace (xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3") from the original xml, however, I would prefer not to do that.

```
DECLARE @ClinicalDocumentXml xml
-- Full document available from http://xreg2.nist.gov/cda-validation/downloads.html
SET @ClinicalDocumentXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd">
    <realmCode code="US"/>
    <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.27.1776" assigningAuthorityName="CDA/R2"/>
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.3" assigningAuthorityName="HL7/CDT Header"/>
    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.1.1" assigningAuthorityName="IHE/PCC"/>
    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.32.1" assigningAuthorityName="HITSP/C32"/>
    <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.72" extension="MU_Rev1_HITSP_C32C83_4Sections_NoInformationEntries_NoErrors" assigningAuthorityName="NIST Healthcare Project"/>
    <code code="34133-9" displayName="Summarization of episode note" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.6.1" codeSystemName="LOINC"/>
    <title/>
    <effectiveTime value="20101026130945"/>
    <confidentialityCode/>
    <languageCode code="en-US"/>
    <recordTarget>
        <patientRole>
            <id root="ProviderID" extension="PatientID" assigningAuthorityName="Provider Name"/>
            <addr use="HP">
                <streetAddressLine>First Address Line</streetAddressLine>
                <streetAddressLine>Next Address line</streetAddressLine>
                <city>CityName</city>
                <state>StateName</state>
                <postalCode>00000-0000</postalCode>
                <country>USA</country>
            </addr>
            <telecom value="tel:+1-(555)555-1212" use="HP" />
            <patient>
                <name>
                    <given>FirstName</given>
                    <given>MiddleNameorInitial</given>
                    <family>FamilyName</family>
                </name>
                <administrativeGenderCode code="F" displayName="Female" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.1" codeSystemName="HL7 AdministrativeGender"/>
                <birthTime value="19840704"/>
                <maritalStatusCode code="S" displayName="Single" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.2" codeSystemName="HL7 Marital status"/>
                <languageCommunication>
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.83.2" assigningAuthorityName="HITSP/C83"/>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.2.1" assigningAuthorityName="IHE/PCC"/>
                    <languageCode code="en-US"/>
                </languageCommunication>
            </patient>
        </patientRole>
    </recordTarget>
</ClinicalDocument>'

SELECT
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";title[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Title,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/id[1]/@extension', 'varchar(255)') AS InternalPatientID,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";effectiveTime[1]/@value', 'varchar(255)') AS CreationDateTime,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/name[1]/name[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FullName,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/name[1]/family[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS LastName,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/name[1]/given[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FirstName,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/name[1]/given[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS MiddleName,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/birthTime[1]/@value', 'varchar(255)') AS DateOfBirth,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/patient[1]/administrativeGenderCode[1]/@code', 'varchar(255)') AS Gender,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/addr[1]/streetAddressLine[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/addr[1]/streetAddressLine[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress2,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/addr[1]/city[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientCity,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/addr[1]/state[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientState,
    Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/addr[1]/postalCode[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientZip,
    Replace(Field.value('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";recordTarget[1]/patientRole[1]/telecom[1]/@value', 'varchar(255)'), 'tel:', '') AS HomePhone
FROM @ClinicalDocumentXml.nodes('declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3"; ClinicalDocument') CCD(Field)
```

Comment: That's nice, but there is no question being asked, and stackoverflow tends to deal with real questions that can be answered in a Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx).

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:hl7-org:v3')
SELECT
    Field.value('title[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Title,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/id/@extension)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS InternalPatientID,
    Field.value('(effectiveTime/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS CreationDateTime,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/name)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FullName,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/family)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS LastName,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/given)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FirstName,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/name/given)[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS MiddleName,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/birthTime/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS DateOfBirth,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/patient/administrativeGenderCode/@code)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Gender,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/addr/streetAddressLine)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/addr/streetAddressLine)[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress2,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/addr/city)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientCity,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/addr/state)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientState,
    Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/addr/postalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientZip,
    Replace(Field.value('(recordTarget/patientRole/telecom/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), 'tel:', '') AS HomePhone
FROM @ClinicalDocumentXml.nodes('ClinicalDocument') CCD(Field)
```

You can also make it a bit shorter by using `cross apply`.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'urn:hl7-org:v3')
SELECT
    CD.Field.value('title[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Title,
    PR.Field.value('(id/@extension)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS InternalPatientID,
    CD.Field.value('(effectiveTime/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS CreationDateTime,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/name/name)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FullName,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/name/family)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS LastName,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/name/given)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS FirstName,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/name/given)[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS MiddleName,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/birthTime/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS DateOfBirth,
    PR.Field.value('(patient/administrativeGenderCode/@code)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Gender,
    PR.Field.value('(addr/streetAddressLine)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress,
    PR.Field.value('(addr/streetAddressLine)[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientAddress2,
    PR.Field.value('(addr/city)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientCity,
    PR.Field.value('(addr/state)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientState,
    PR.Field.value('(addr/postalCode)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS PatientZip,
    Replace(PR.Field.value('(telecom/@value)[1]', 'varchar(255)'), 'tel:', '') AS HomePhone
FROM
  (SELECT @ClinicalDocumentXml.query('/ClinicalDocument/*')) AS CD(Field)
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CD.Field.query('recordTarget/patientRole/*')) AS PR(Field)
```

Answer (score 1):

A trivial change that might at least help reduce line-wrap:

```
DECLARE @namespace varchar(75);
SET @namespace = 'declare default element namespace "urn:hl7-org:v3";';

SELECT 
   Field.value(@namespace + 'title[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Title,
   ...
```